# Pass in only strings and ints in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a function like the below. I ran into a problem were i accidentally passes in enums when i wanted the value. Same problem would occur if i passed in structs or classes.

Is there a way i can pass call the func and only have strings and ints as my arguments?

```
static public string Func(string fmt, params object[] args)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a paramarray of a specific type.
If you want to accept two different types, you can create a class with implicit conversions from `int` and `string` and accept a paramarray of that class.

Comment: +1 - tested it and it worked. It frightens me that this is legal. I would encourage the OP to revise the design instead.

Comment: Yes; I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I know this is a dup because I remember coming up with reasons that you might legitimately want to do this. If only I could find it...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the first parameter is used to communicate the format of the data in the second parameter, the array.

I would create two public methods to solve this by making use of method overloading.
see http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading.  I believe this will work for array parameters.

static public Func(string[] args) ...
and 
static public Func(int[] args) ...

Comment: It will work, but what if the OP wants to mix ints and strings in a single call?

Comment: Agreed...but from the example in the question, I assumed the first parameter, fmt, indicated that the calling method must specify the format of data in the array.

Comment: I think the OP's trying to recreate [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx). If that's the case then it may just contain a string with placeholders. Unlike printf, the placeholders do not have to specify a type.

Comment: "strings **and** ints as my **arg** ument **s**" ;)